# How jng works in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I need to make a `sub` if bl>7fh
The code I'm using is:

```
cmp bl,7fh
jng  here
sub bl,bl
here:
```

I know bl>7fh because bl=92 and `jng` is *jump if bl is not greater than* 7fh
In this case bl is greater than 7fh so why it jumps?!

Comment: Testing for `> 0x7F` is an interesting special case.  You're testing if `bl` has its highest bit set.  You can use a signed test for negative, after comparing `bl` against zero.  If it's the result of the last instruction that set flags, the sign flag (`SF`) will already be set according to whether `bl` is negative or not, so you might even be able to leave out a `test` instruction.  But anyway, `test bl,bl` / `jns here` / `xor bl,bl` will do the trick.  (`xor` is the normal choice for zeroing a reg).  You could also use `cmovs ebx,something` instead of branching, but there is no 8-bit cmov.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition for `jng` is *signed* not greater than. Depending on whether you meant 92 or 92h that would be either 92 or -110 when interpreted as a signed byte. In any case, that's less than 127 (7Fh), which means that `jng` should jump.

What you want is an *unsigned* not greater than (the name for that is "not above" or "below or equal"). I.e.

```
jna here   ; or jbe here
```

Comment: finally a clear and simple answer!  Thank you so much :)!